# PHP curl post request to server using cloudflare (Full SSL) has SSL error and Blank SESSION Cookie

Tags: php, session, ssl, curl, cloudflare

Hi I'm doing a website right now. Both of these files is in one server and domain and I'm using cloudflare to boost the loading. I'm using Full SSL option on cloudflare because I bought my own SSL Geotrust on my server. I already upgraded my curl on the server to 7.41.0.

One php file consist of the function

**Function File:**

```
<?php
function get_content($session){
    $endpoint = "https://sample.ph/php/resource.php";
    // Use one of the parameter configurations listed at the top of the post
    $params = array(
        "yel" => $session
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$endpoint);
    $strCookie = 'PHPSESSID='.$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
    $postData = "";

    //This is needed to properly form post the credentials object
    foreach($params as $k => $v)
    {
       $postData .= $k . '='.urlencode($v).'&';
    }
    $postData = rtrim($postData, '&');

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // Don’t return the header, just the html
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO,"/home/sample/public_html/php/cacert.pem"); // Set the location of the CA-bundle

    session_write_close();
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($response === FALSE) {
    return "cURL Error: " . curl_error($curl);
    }
    else{
    // evaluate for success response
    return $response;   
    }
    curl_close($curl);
}
?>
```

**Resource File**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['yel'])){

$drcyt_key = dcrypt("{$_POST['yel']}");

  if($drcyt_key == $_SESSION['token']){
   echo "Success";

  }
}
?>
```

How do you think will I fix this?

1. The SSL Verification error. Upon debugging sometimes I got cURL Error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
2. Sometimes I got cURL Error: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
3. When I put curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); to FALSE, which is not a good idea; There comes a second problem for the SESSION COOKIE becoming blank on first load.

I HOPE YOU CAN HELP ME. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

This issue looks to be an outdated certificate bundle or outdated OpenSSL version on the server. You should both ensure you have the latest root certificates on your computer and also ensure that you have the latest versions of OpenSSL (including the PHP OpenSSL module).